# How can I add a missing website to Google Maps for my business

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-maps, google-my-business

I added my business on Google, but it shows my website information is missing and I don't know why.

Please check here: `https://www.google.com/search?q=Hit+Infotech+LLP`

[image]

I already added my website many times and it was approved, as you can see below, but it is still missing:

[image]

I searched a lot for a solution but still have not resolved this. Please let me know if you have a solution or a step forward.

Comment: Did you use the same Google account you claimed the business with? If so, and you followed [this](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7084895), then you can try to send [feedback](https://www.wikihow.com/Contact-Google-Maps) on the listing, or post in their forum [here](https://support.google.com/maps/community?hl=en).

Comment: It shows up for me under GMB when I use your query